# How to inherit URL fragment from parent inside an `iframe`

Tags: html, iframe

I have a webpage with a "html reference manual", where I sent anchored URL links, e.g. like this:

http://www.vanillaware.de/plotFields/docs/html/plotFieldsDoc.html#prp/x

This opens automatically the page in the browser jumping to the referred anchor. This is the behavior I expect.

Now I want to embed this HTML page within another page using `<iframe>`, but still being able to send an URL link with an anchor. Unfortunately this doesn't work with this simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p><iframe src="plotFieldsDoc.html"></iframe></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Using a similar URL link as above:

[http://www.vanillaware.de/plotFields/docs/html/tryUrlAnchor2.html#prp/x](http://www.vanillaware.de/plotFields/docs/html/tryUrlAnchor2.html#prp%2Fx)

Did I made something wrong and is there a simple way to reach my goal?

Comment: What do you mean that is not working? Do you want that the links on that iframe when being clicked will still load inside that iframe?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear: The second URL I posted has got an anchor at the end. Thus I expect (would like to) that when a user types this URL in the browser, that within the `iframe` the browser jumps/scrolls to the anchor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inline `onload` event handler to reassign `location.hash` inside the `iframe` to match that of its parent page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p><iframe src="plotFieldsDoc.html" onload="this.contentDocument.location.hash=location.hash"></iframe></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You changed the title of my original post. To be honest I don't know if my "problem" refers to this new title. However I tried your solution and I still havn't got the behaviour I expect. See here
http://www.vanillaware.de/plotFields/docs/html/tryUrlAnchor3.html#prp/x

Comment: Should be fixed now. Try the updated code and let me know if it works.

Comment: Now it works, see here
http://www.vanillaware.de/plotFields/docs/html/tryUrlAnchor3.html#prp/x

Comment: Glad it worked! An accept would always be appreciated if you have the time :)

Comment: Yes, for sure, this is the least I can do :-)

Comment: Ups, could you please correct the first link in my firts post back to its original value, as now the text is misleading.

Comment: Which link did you want me to correct? You should be able to edit your own posts, if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: You distorted the link to a different one, so I believed there was a reason you did this. I reset the URL link now to the original post.